# Usted ha retenido paquetes rotos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cmd, debian

He hecho los comandos correspondientes para instalar albert y al final cuando lo quise instalar utilizando

```
    sudo apt install albert
```

me sale el error de que los paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas diciendo lo siguiente

> Albert: depende : libpython 3.7 igual o mayor a esta version pero no es instalable

E: no se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Intente comandos para reparar paquetes como

```
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
    sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
    sudo apt-get install -f
```

Pero no se soluciona imagino que ya que los paquetes no estan ni instalados.